# How can I add a custom authentication attribute to Web API using OWIN Security?

Tags: vb.net, api, model-view-controller, oauth, owin

Normally I would require authentication to a controller like this:

```
Namespace Controllers
    <Authorize(Users:="user1")>
    Public Class Module1Controller
        Inherits ApiController

        ' GET: api/Module1
        Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)

            Return New String() {"This", "is", "Module1", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name}
        End Function
```

But instead of that, we are wanting to authenticate using the same method, except have a list of users pulled from a local database table (in SSMS) along with the controllers they have access to and check against them to see if they have access to a particular controller (Module1 in this example). So I've followed a couple of examples on creating a custom authentication attribute, but I can't get it to work. The idea is to implement this class:

```
Public Class CustomAuthorize
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
    Protected Function AuthorizeCore(ByVal httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean
        Dim users As String() = {"user1", "user2"}
        If users.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name) Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

where the string array would, in reality, be filled from a database query and then use `<CustomAuthorize>` at the top of the controller instead of `<Authorize(Users:="user1">`... But when I run it, it never makes it into the CustomAuthorize class. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working:

```
Public Class CustomAuthorize
    Inherits System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    Protected Overrides Function IsAuthorized(ByVal actionContext As System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext) As Boolean
        Dim users As String() = {"user1", "user2"}
        If users.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name) Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```